# compilation warning: no rule to process file for architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, compiler-construction

How can I resolve this warning?

> [WARN]warning: no rule to process file
>   '$(PROJECT_DIR)/MyApp/MessageCell.h' of type sourcecode.objj.h for
>   architecture i386

Comment: It also says that it is trying to compile your header files as sourcecode.objj.h from Objective-J (which also uses .h files for headers), do you have Cappuccino installed?

Answer (score 587, accepted):

Click on your project, and check that this file is not present in the tab Build Phases. Normally no header files should stay here. Clean and build it again, it should work!

Comment: i have a few headers files in there. Just curious, why shouldn't headers be there?

Comment: Because this is the list of source files that will be compiled, and _normally_ you have already included <file>.h inside your <file>.m

Comment: Whenever I create a new class, my XCode is automatically adding the header files to my build phases. I don't know why, anyone has a clue why this happens? Currently each time I create a new class I need to delete the header files from the build phases manually.

Comment: I might add that a .h file may appear in the build phases (when it's not supposed to) because the .m file has (by mistake) a different name.

Comment: this'd make perfect sense... I had created the file originally as a .cpp then renamed it to a .h

Comment: I have the same issue, however I only have .m files in build phases. No problem if i386 arch is removed.

Answer (score 36):

Graphical guide for Xcode 4.x to remove this warning:

http://joytek.blogspot.tw/2011/09/xcode-4-warning-no-rule-to-process-file.html

Answer (score 20):

We can resolve this issue by simply following the steps below:-
Some `.md`, `.mdown` `.h` files are included in the **Compile Sources** 
Step 1) Select Project Navigator
Step 2) Select your project
Step 3) Select your targetStep 
Step 4) Select Build PhasesStep 
Step 5) Move files which we don't want the compiler to process from **Compile Sources** to **Copy Bundle Resources**

[Check this](http://xcodar.blogspot.in/2015/01/warning-no-rule-to-process-file-of-type.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting this warning from your cocoapod you ned to make sure the `s.source_files` is set correctly in the `.podspec`.

For example I originally included all files with this line in my `.podspec`

```
s.source_files = "MyUIElements/**/*"
```

I was getting this compilation warning for some font files I had in the pod. You control which files show up in `BuildPhases` -> `CompileSources` on pod consumption like this:

```
s.source_files = "MyUIElements/**/*.swift", "MyUIElements/**/*.h"
```

Comment: or `s.source_files = "Sources**/*.{h,m,swift}"`?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was't header files because under `Target` > `Build Phases` > `Compile Resources` there weren't any `.h files` to begin with. The system was complaining about some other files. I followed [this link](https://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-fix-no-rule-to-process-file-warning-in-xcode/) which basically said delete the files the system was complaining about but instead I cntrl + dragged them to `Copy Bundle Resources`.

The easiest way to search for the files is to use the Filter in the upper right hand corner:

[image]

Here are the directions from the link:

[image]