# Loading html5 pages which use javascript into a webview for a native iOS App

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, uiwebview, webview

Was wondering if anyone knew how to load html5 pages which use javascript into a webview in XCode. I keep getting errors and the main one is `warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/donk/javascript/highlight.pack.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386` I have seen apps that can do this. Can someone please let me know how to do this? Would be forever greatful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you are getting is probably due to the build settings.

See this similar answer:

[compilation warning: no rule to process file for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509600/compilation-warning-no-rule-to-process-file-for-architecture-i386)

Comment: Hey errolc, I looked at the answer which states "to not put files in the tab Build Phases". I am not sure what that means?

Comment: In Xcode select the project in the Project Navigator, then select the Target. Select the Build Phases tab, make sure the .js files are not listed in the Compile Sources section.

Comment: Okay slightly confused as to how I am to go about making this work. I have an html page, an image, and a javascript file to make the html5 page work. So where am i supposed to put all of these files then? :(

Comment: Sorry I can't help you there. My initial comment was trying to help remove the warning.

Comment: Could this help? I think you need to put your page in your resources folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645414/how-can-i-load-a-local-html-file-into-the-uiwebview

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Thank you errolc for your feedback