# What is no rule to process file mean?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/YIFullScreenScrollDemo/../../Classes/UIViewController+YIFullScreenScroll.m' of type file for architecture i386
```

I am trying to implement YIFullScreenScrollDemo

After keep failing I just copy the whole .h and .m file to the main project. Actually I keep reference.

Now this code for example, pass compile check:

```
self.fullScreenScroll = [[YIFullScreenScroll alloc] initWithViewController:self scrollView:self.tableView];
```

Yet, at run time, I got:

```
YIFullScreenScrollDemo[82387:c07] -[FirstViewController setFullScreenScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7577e80
```

Also I got these 4 warnings:

```
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/YIFullScreenScrollDemo/../../Classes/UIViewController+YIFullScreenScroll.m' of type file for architecture i386
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/YIFullScreenScrollDemo/../../Classes/YIFullScreenScroll.m' of type file for architecture i386
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/YIFullScreenScrollDemo/../Pods/JRSwizzle/JRSwizzle.m' of type file for architecture i386
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/YIFullScreenScrollDemo/../../Classes/UIView+YIFullScreenScroll.m' of type file for architecture i386
```

What is the problem?

Note: not duplicate of the other one [compilation warning: no rule to process file for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509600/compilation-warning-no-rule-to-process-file-for-architecture-i386)

This one is for .m files. The other question is for .h file

Naturally we do need to include the .m files right?

Comment: Duplicate : Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509600/compilation-warning-no-rule-to-process-file-for-architecture-i386

Comment: That's for .h file. This is for .m file

Comment: Did you try that answer?

Comment: The answer says we should get rid the .h file from compile lists. I can't do that for .m file.

Comment: it seems like your xcode settings are messed up... The warning means that xcode doesnt know what it should do to compile a .m file. is this project specific or for all projects

Comment: Here is what I did: Move buggy moves down the list (in complied resources list), clean, close xcode, reopen, clean again, build, boom it worked!

Comment: I have this same problem. Every single `.m` file in a static library is giving me this warning and a clean doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 6):

What mojtaba said works for .m files (+1) in the event that you don't have the .h issue people are referring to.

Click on the Product menu, hold ALT to enable the "Clean Build Folder..." option and then recompile. Error went away.