# mp3 file do not play with smartface 4.3 xcode output

Tags: smartface.io

If you run the code to play mp3 file everything is ok with device emulation.
But if you plublish the project to excode and try to run mp3 it fails to run mp3 file with warnning "no rule tp proccess file '.../audio.mp3" for architecture arm7 arm64 "
Some solution exist?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean - build of the solution ?

Some questions answered like this [compilation warning: no rule to process file for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509600/compilation-warning-no-rule-to-process-file-for-architecture-i386)

But I guess it is about 64Bit compile problem. Can you try to remove arm64 from build list and be sure to using latest XCode.